# How can I get a regular expression to find the correct instance of a word?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I'm trying to write a regular expression in python to identify instances of the phrases "played for" and "plays for" in a text, with the potential for finding instances where words come between the two, for example, "played guitar for". I only want this to find the first instance of the word "for" after "plays" or "played", however, I cannot work out how to write the regular expression.

The code I have at the moment is like this:

```
def play_finder(doc)
    playre = re.compile(r'\bplay[s|e][d]?\b.*\bfor\b\s\b')
    if playre.findall(doc):
        for inst in playre.findall(doc):
            playstr = inst
            print(playstr)

mytext = "He played for four hours last night. He plays guitar for the foo pythers. He won an award for his guitar playing."

play_finder(mytext)
```

I would like my to be able to pull out two instances from `mytext`; "played for four" and "plays guitar for the".

Instead, what my code is finding is:

> "He played for four hours last night. He plays guitar for the foo pythers. He won an award for".

So it's skipping the first and second for, and only finding the last.

How can I rewrite the regular expression to get it to stop skipping over the first and second instance of "for" in the sentence, and to identify both of them?

Edit: Another problem has become apparent to me after applying a solution I was offered. Given more than one sentence, such as:

> "He played an eight hour set. It seemed like he went on for ever."

I don't want the regex to identify "He played an eight hour set. It seemed like he went on for" as matching the pattern. Is there a way to stop it looking for the "for" if it encounters a full stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
\bplay(?:s|ed).*?for\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/97)

There are some faults in the regex of your script.

```
playre = re.compile(r'\bplay[s|e][d]?\b.*\bfor\b\s\b')
```

- `[s|e]` : is not workable for logical expression because `[]` is `character class` and means only one character which it allows
- `.*` : `greed(*) search` seems match the string of possible maximum length match.

Comment: It's a typo. In this case, it's meaningless

Comment: The code you suggested - \bplay(s|ed).*?for\b - seems to only return two strings, "s" and "ed", depending whether "play" or "played" is used in a given doc. Is that by design?

Comment: Because `findall()` do store capture values first. if there's no capture group in regex, then store full match value each time. pls try again, I edited the regex to non capture group.

Comment: That's working much better, however, it's outlined another problem I hadn't considered. I've edited my original post to include this, but in summary, this regex doesn't stop at the end of a line, so the "plays/ed" and the "for" can be part of two separate sentences.

Comment: I recommend you note that `[...]` is called `character class` and means one character which is included in the `set` which is represented by `[...something...] `. And I'll happy to see you understand search modifier `lazy`, `greedy`, and `possessive`(or `atomic group`). Thank you:-)

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand the use of square brackets. They create a character class which matches a single character out of the set of characters enumerated between the brackets. So `[s|e]` matches `s` or `|` or `e`.

Also, the word boundary is simply an assertion. It matches if the previous character was a "word" character and the next one isn't, or vice versa; but it doesn't advance the position within the string. So, for example, `\s\bfor\b\s` is redundant; we already know that `\s` matches whitespace (which is non-word) and `for` consists of word characters. You mean simply `\sfor\s` because the dropped `\b` conditions don't change what is being matched.

Try

```
r'\bplay(?:s|ed)?\s+(?:\w+\s+)??for\s+\w+'
```

The `(?:\w+\s+)??` allows for a single optional word before `for`. The second question mark makes the capture non-greedy, i.e. it matches the shortest possible string which still allows the expression to match, instead of the longest. You will not want to allow unlimited repetitions (because then you'd match e.g.  "played another game before he sat down for") but you might consider replacing the `??` with e.g. `{0,3}?` to allow for up to three words before "for".

We use `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` to make the grouping parentheses non-capturing; otherwise, `findall` will return a list of the captured submatches rather than the entire match.

The `if findall: for findall` is a minor inefficiency; you just need `for match in findall` which will simply iterate zero times if there are no matches.

More generally, using regex for higher-level grammatical patterns is very often unsatisfactory. A grammatical parser (even some type of shallow parsing) is better at telling you when some words are constituents of an optional attribute or modifier for a noun phrase, or when "play" should be analyzed as a noun. Consider

> He played - or rather, tapped his fingers and hummed - for three minutes.
>
> I play another silly but not completely outrageous role for the third time in a year.
>
> She plays what for many is considered offensive gameplay for the Hawks.
>
> Brett plays the oboe although he thinks it's for wimps.
>
> Some plays are for fools.

Comment: I tried a few iterations of this suggestion. The one that worked best was:

    r'\bplay(s|ed)?\s+(\w+\s+){0,9}for\s+\w+'

Still, this didn't return what I was expecting. For the sentence "played as a guitarist for..." it returned `('s', 'winger ')` rather than the text itself. It also missed the second instance "played...for" in the paragraph. Is this what you intended it to do?

Comment: The input string doesn't contain "winger" so I don't see how it could return that. Maybe look into replacing each opening parenthesis with `(?:` to make it non-grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody answered that I needed the lazy `.*?` then deleted their answer. I'm not sure why, because that worked. Hence, the code I'm using now is:

```
(r'\bplay[s|e][d]?\b.*?\bfor\b\s\b')
```

@ThmLee I tried your suggestion:

```
\bplay(s|ed).*?for\b
```

I'm (clearly) no expert with Regex, but it seemed not to work as well. Instead of outputting the lines "played for" and " plays guitar for" it just outputs "s" and "ed".

Comment: You still mean `[se]` unless you are really looking for `play|`. The bar is not an alteration operator inside square brackets, it's just one among the bracketed characters. Also `play[se][d]?` matches "playsd`.

Comment: I'm a beginner with regular expressions. It's not technically correct, but it seemed to work for me. @ThmLee has suggested a more eloquent solution which I'm now using.